# Custom C++ extension : torch/torch.h not found

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am following [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) to create a C++ extension for Pytorch. My C++ code is giving following error :

```
test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: torch/torch.h: No such file or directory
 #include <torch/torch.h>
```

How to get `torch.h` header file ? Is there some `pytorch-dev` version?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to install the c++ version of torch.

If you head over to www.pytorch.org they will guide you to which download is appropriate for you. Just make sure to select the c++ version.

Hopefully that works!